# Handlebars template not filling in context

Tags: javascript, templates

I'm building a `Flask` application and have some client-side HTML rendering which I would like to do using `Handlebars` templates.

I have the following very basic handlebars template:

```
<script id="source-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
    <div class="source-data">
        <span>{{last4}}</span>
        <span>Exp : {{exp_month}} / {{exp_year}}</span>
    </div>
</script>
```

And I am using it as follows (exactly as in the handlebars tutorial):

```
var source = $('#source-template').html();
var template = Handlebars.compile(source);
var context ={
    last4:'1234',
    exp_month:'12',
    exp_year:'2020'
};  
var html = template(context);
console.log(html);
```

However it doesn't seem to be inserting the data from my context into the template.  The console output is:

```
<div class="source-data">
    <span></span>
    <span>Exp : / </span>
</div>
```

Am I missing something here?  I'm not sure what could be going wrong, as I essentially copied the [handlebars example](http://handlebarsjs.com/).

Comment: It seems that there is an issue in its installation. Could you see any errors in the console?.

Comment: Check out [**this demo**](http://jsbin.com/hukobulopi/edit?html,console,output)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since I am using `Flask`, I had the script written in an html file which was rendered by `Jinja`.

Because there were no variables named `last4`, `exp_month`, `or exp_year` passed into Flask's `render_template()` function, it replaced them with nothing, leaving the handlebars template with no variables.

The solution for this was to use `{% raw %}` around the script so that Jinja wouldn't interpret these as variables:

```
<script id="source-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
    {% raw %}
    <div class="source-data">
        <span>{{last4}}</span>
        <span>Exp : {{exp_month}} / {{exp_year}}</span>
    </div>
    {% endraw %}
</script>
```

Comment: The same issue will occur in Django. To prevent Django from parsing the templates, Handlebar templates should be wrapped in a verbatim block, {% verbatim %} ... handlebar templates go here ... {% endverbatim %}